# PHP inside JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have one line of JavaScript that I'd appreciate help with.

```
req.open("GET", 'update.php?id=<?php $id ?>', true);
```

Where $id = 12345, I am trying to get the contents of update.php?id=12345.

Using PHP inside this JavaScript doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `<?= $id ?>`. But you should think about separating JS from PHP. That will become a mess real quick...

Comment: @elclanrs That didn't work. :(

Comment: Make sure you have shortags enabled or just `<?php echo $id ?>`. The problem is that you're not actually printing anything.

Comment: or use <?php echo $id; ?> some servers don't allow this short tags

Comment: Sorry, I tried `<?php echo $id; ?>` already. I should have included that in my question.

Comment: "PHP inside JavaScript" does not exist and will never work. What you can do is let the *server* process the file as PHP script, so that it returns valid JavaScript/HTML.

Comment: dude you need to echo it...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi, As he said in his comments, he's already tried that.

Comment: check the path of the file you are accessing. try to access it manually in the browser..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out myself. The value for id was coming from a parameter in the URL and I hadn't included `$_GET['id'];`.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure that you are actually inside a PHP file, or have your server configured to process whatever file extension you are using with PHP.

Then, you can echo data directly into the JavaScript.  For best compatibility and to avoid potential XSS vulnerabilities, always JSON-encode the data.

```
req.open('GET', 'update.php?id=' + <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>, true);
```

Personally, I prefer to have a block of variables that are assigned over from PHP.  this keeps your JavaScript cleaner.

```
<?php
    $options = new stdClass();
    $options->id = 12345;
    $options->dinnerSelection = 'pizza';

    echo 'var options = ', json_encode($options), ';'
?>

// Then later on in your JS...
req.open('GET', 'update.php?id=' + options.id, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some way to do this.
First one make your javascript file in .php file(be carrefull you need to include it and not to link it in the begin of file.

Second one, in php, you can wrote

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
   id="'.$id.'";
</script>';
?>
```

with this, you define a global variable in javascript who take the good value.
Then you just have to wrote after this :

```
req.open("GET", 'update.php?id='+id, true);
```

if you have to change the id after requied the page, you just have to change the id javascript value

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be a very poor design decision to use PHP to format your javascript in this way. You should provide more info about what you're trying to do because I can almost guarantee you that there is a better way to do this.
If you are trying to, for instance, do a javascript call to a URL (clearly), then apply that data to an attribute in the HTML document:

```
<div id="someExample">
   <a href="http://www.whocares.com" data-id="12345">Item 12345</a>
</div>
```

And then use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to access that item when clicked, cancelling the link's default action if necessary. The benefits of this approach are many- you can write reusable code, and you don't have extra PHP parsing to do in a javascript that is going to be extremely hard to understand later.

Adding JS hardcoded data via PHP to a javascript object is a very poor design decision. If you need more help on this let me know, but try researching it more first!